# gridline/ticklines in dashed in canvas in flot.js

Tags: flot

How can I create dashed lines in both **x-axis** and **y-axis** in `flot.js`? I don't know where to change in library. This is my code Of generated graph on canvas using `flot.js`. But I want the **Dashed Lines** on **x-axis** and **y-axis** on grid background in canvas.  I try `markingsStyle: 'dashed'` but that did not work.

```
plot = $.plot("#placeholder", [{
            dashes: { show: true },
            data: data,
            color: "rgb(255, 255, 255)",
            label: $("#hidsymbolid").val(),                    
        }, {
            data: dataBaseLine,
            color: "rgb(255, 255, 255)",
            lineStyle: "dashed"
        }
        ], {
            series: {
                lines: {
                    lineWidth: 1,
                    show: true,
                    lineJoin: "round",
                    lineCap: "round"
                },
                points: {                    
                    show: false
                }
            },
            grid: {
                hoverable: true,
                backgroundColor: {
                    colors: ["#3B3B3B", "#3B3B3B"]
                },                 
                markingsStyle: 'dashed'
            },         
            xaxis: {
                show: true,
                tickSize: parseFloat((maxvalue - minvalue) / 6),
                min: minvalue,
                max: maxvalue,
                dashes: { show: true },
                timeformat: "%H:%M:%S",              
                tickColor: "rgb(255, 255, 255)",            
            },
            yaxis: {
                show: true,
                dashes: { show: true },
                color: "rgb(255, 255, 255)",
                alignTicksWithAxis: 2               
            }
});
```

Comment: Hi and welcome. Your question is not clear, please elaborate on your problem with specific code sample.

Comment: possible duplicate of [dashed ticklines/gridlines in flot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14700417/dashed-ticklines-gridlines-in-flot)

Comment: its not working with my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this.

**setLineDash([5])**

**Example:-**
      `var context = document.querySelector("canvas");`
  `var cxt = context..getContext('2d');`
  `cxt.beginPath();`
  `cxt.setLineDash([9]);`
  `cxt.rect(30,15,100,100);`
  `cxt.stroke();`